# How to get a loop to work in VBA?

Tags: vba, excel

I have been starting to learn loops in VBA and for some reason, I cannot get this code to work.

```
Sub test()

Dim Sheet1 As Worksheet
Dim fr As Long
Dim c As Long

Set Sheet1 = Worksheets("Sheet1")

fr = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

    With Sheet1

        For c = fr To step - 1
            If .Cells(c, "A").Value = "" Then
                .Cells(c, "A").EntireRow.Clear
            End If
            Next c
    End With

End Sub
```

All I am trying to do is if in column A, if there is no value to clear the entire row. Yet, this code is not working for me and I cannot figure out why.

Any help would be greatly appreaciated.

Thanks,

G

Comment: When do you want the loop to stop? You need to put that between `to` and `step`.

Comment: Either `For c = fr To 1 step - 1` or  `For c = fr To 2 step - 1` ; depends where your data starts and whether you have a column header label.

Comment: Simple as that. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Start by putting `Option Explicit` at the top of the module. This forces you to declare all of your variables, and will cause a compile error that points out your problem. In this line...

```
For c = fr To step - 1
```

... you are missing the end point for the loop. What you probably *meant* there was...

```
For c = fr To 1 Step - 1
```

Note that the keyword `Step` is lower-cased in your code.  That is because the VBA parser is looking for the expression `For X = Y To Z [Step #]`, where `[Step #]` is optional. Since the `Z` was missing and required, it parsed `step - 1` as an expression, subtracting 1 from the ***undeclared variable*** `step`. Since numeric variables are initialized as `0`, you are overrunning the start of the sheet.

Comment: @Jeeped For someone as generally lazy as I am, you'd think I'd have that turned on by now...

Answer (score 2):

You have an incomplete For ... Next and your cell references are mismatched. Sheet1 is very likely the worksheet codename and shouldn't be reused.

```
Sub test()

    Dim ws1 As Worksheet
    Dim fr As Long, c As Long

    Set ws1 = Worksheets("Sheet1")


    With ws1
        fr = .Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

        For c = fr To 1 step - 1
            If .Cells(c, "A").Value = "" Then
                .Cells(c, "A").EntireRow.Clear
            End If
        Next c
    End With

End Sub
```